# PDF toUnicode cmap table restore

Tags: pdf, unicode, ghostscript

I have multiple pdf files without 'toUnicode' cmap table. Absence of cmap table restricts me from copying the text from pdf files.

As far as I know, there is a possibility to add 'toUnicode' mapping in pdf file, but in my case adding static values is not an option, different files have different glyph codes.

So the question is the following. Is there any possibility to restore 'toUnicode' cmap table, perhaps with the help of Ghostscript, or are there any options at all?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot add ToUnicode CMaps to an existing PDF file using Ghostscript.

In the general case, you can't do it at all, except manually. As you note in the question, different files will be constructed to use different character code->Glyph mappings, which means that the character code to Unicode mapping will also be different.

Since the character code selection is often based on the order in which glyphs are used in a file (so the fist glyph is character code 1, the second is character code 2 etc) you can see that there is no prospect of identifying a 'one size fits all' solution.

You could use some kind of OCR to scan the rendered output, identify each glyph and find the Unicode code point for it. Then you could construct a CMap by identifying the character code for the glyph and mapping it to the Unicode value.

You could, then, add the ToUnicode CMap to the PDF file, and update the Font Descriptor with the object number of the ToUnicode CMap.

Ghostscript won't do any of that for you, and I haven't heard of any tool which will.